# Adding IdentityServer4 to a Django API as an OAuth2 Server

Tags: python, django, identityserver4

I have a Python API written using Django. I am going to use IdentityServer4 as my OAuth2 server to generate JWT for the Django application so I can add other frameworks like .NET Core to my solution later without any issues.

Is that possible to use IdentityServer4 as an OAuth2 server for Django?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. According to the website of IdentityServer4, IdentityServer4 is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET Core.

You can try with the demo server: https://demo.identityserver.io/

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/big_picture.html

Please note that according the homepage of IdentityServer4, the development of the IdentityServer4 has been stopped and IdentityServer4 will be maintained with security updates until November 2022.

Comment: I appreciate if you pay attention to the question I have asked and answer that if you can. I didn't ask about the capability of using IdentityServer4 in general and for .NET apps. My question was specifically about Django.

Comment: hi. Did you ever get the answer to this question?

Comment: @Ali I have answered at the beginning